# MYSQl export result set csv and send it as out param or variable through a proc

Tags: mysql, file, export

i found link web which tell how to export result set to OUTFILE.
http://sandaldjepit.com/2009/how-to-export-mysql-data-table-to-excel-csv-format-with-sql-query/

But I want store the resultset in a longtext variable return it as out parameter or sent as 1 row, 1 column record ,like:

select str;

I have tried to do work around by using concat and group_concat, but if any value is null the whole str will become null.

Can anyone suggest a work around.
I am ok, if i have to write the result to the OUTFILE and then load to variable.
As i wont have control to local file system, its better the file is saved to a place where mysql has access.

Or any other idea with code is welcomed.

Please guide me through

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ifnull(col_name, "")` function. If a specific column is null, it uses an empty string instead.